# Using node-static and journey together

Tags: node.js, journey, node-static

I'm using Node.js for the first time. I'm serving up static files with [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) and routing with [journey](https://github.com/cloudhead/journey). Unfortunately the two seem to conflict with each other, and I'm not sure of the best way to stop the conflict. My server looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var nodeStatic = require('node-static');
var journey = require('journey');

var fileServer = new nodeStatic.Server('./public');
var router = new journey.Router;


module.exports = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  router.get('/api').bind(function (req, res) {
    res.send(200);
  });
var fileServer = new nodeStatic.Server('./public');
var router = new journey.Router;


module.exports = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  router.get('/api').bind(function (req, res) {
    res.send(200);
  });

  req.addListener('end', function () {
    fileServer.serve(req, res);

    router.handle(req, '', function (result) {
      res.writeHead(result.status, result.headers);
      res.end(result.body);
    });
  });
});
```

The problem with this is that the Journey router sends a 404 response. The only way I've managed to make it work is by doing this in the `end` listener:

```
  req.addListener('end', function () {
    router.handle(req, '', function (result) {
      if (result.status === 404) {
        fileServer.serve(req, res);
      }
      else {
        res.writeHead(result.status, result.headers);
        res.end(result.body);
      }
    });
  });
```

but this doesn't seem like the way I should be handling things. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a gist showing how to use node-static with journey](https://gist.github.com/708119). I basically had it right. I'd be happy to hear any alternative solutions though!